# Create Step Functions from JSON File in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

With an existing Step Functions definition JSON file, how can I use it directly in CDK to create a Step Function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the L1 `CfnStateMachine` construct. It has a [definitionString](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions.CfnStateMachine.html#definitionstring) prop that accepts a stringified JSON definition.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the code snippet if it is useful to anyone.

```js
  private createStepFunction(props: {
    stepfunction_name: string;
    stepfunctions_role_arn: string;
  }): stepfunctions.CfnStateMachine {
    const file = fs.readFileSync("../step_functions/definition.asl.json");

    const stepFunction = new stepfunctions.CfnStateMachine(
      this,
      "cfnStepFunction",
      {
        roleArn: props.stepfunctions_role_arn,
        definitionString: file.toString(),
        stateMachineName: props.stepfunction_name,
      }
    );

    return stepFunction;
  }
```